# using PL/SQL assoc array index by varchar2 in C#

Tags: c#, plsql

I have PL/SQL code:

```
create or replace 
package        TEST_PKG2 as
  type AssocArray is table of varchar2(20) index by binary_integer;
  type AssocArray_varchar is table of varchar2(20) index by varchar2(10);
  --type AssocArray_varchar is table of varchar2(20) index by integer;

  function assoc_arry_return(Param1 in AssocArray) return AssocArray_varchar;
end TEST_PKG2;

create or replace 
package body        TEST_PKG2 as 
  function assoc_arry_return(Param1 in AssocArray) return AssocArray_varchar
    is
  v_return_value AssocArray_varchar;    
  begin
    v_return_value('name1'):=Param1(1);
    v_return_value('name2'):=Param1(2);
    v_return_value('name3'):=Param1(3);

    return v_return_value;
  end assoc_arry_return;
end TEST_PKG2;
```

controle code to check pl/sql:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  assoc_array test_pkg2.AssocArray;
  assoc_array_return test_pkg2.AssocArray_varchar;

begin
  assoc_array(1):='test1';
  assoc_array(2):='test2';
  assoc_array(3):='test3';
  assoc_array_return:= test_pkg2.assoc_arry_return(assoc_array);
  dbms_output.put_line(assoc_array_return.first||' - '||assoc_array_return(assoc_array_return.first));
end;
```

and C# code for execute this function:

```
command = new OracleCommand("TEST_PKG2.assoc_arry_return", OracleConnection);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                OracleParameter return_value = new OracleParameter();
                return_value.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
                return_value.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                return_value.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
                return_value.Size=3;
                return_value.ArrayBindSize = new int[3] { 20, 20, 20 };
                command.Parameters.Add(return_value);

                OracleParameter Param4 = command.Parameters.Add("Param1", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                Param4.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                Param4.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
                Param4.Value = new string[3] { "First Element", "Second Element", "Third Element" };
                Param4.Size = 3;
                Param4.ArrayBindSize = new int[3] { 20, 20, 20 };
                Param4.ArrayBindStatus = new OracleParameterStatus[3] { OracleParameterStatus.Success, OracleParameterStatus.Success, OracleParameterStatus.Success };
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When I execute app with thic code, execution dies on last line with error "ORA-06550: Line 1, column 15:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: Line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored"

This is a special case, when I use assoc array indexed by varchar2.
when I change index by of return type in package on integer (commented out line code id package), all is OK.

Do you have any idea how use this package in C#?

Thank's

Comment: Last time I checked the ODP.NET (10.2), it wasn't capable of handling `varchar2`-indexed collections. I somehow doubt that it changed over time. (Btw. I like that "riadok" and "stĺpec". :-))

Answer (score 0):

Although nor [ODP.NET Developer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E41125_02/featOraCommand.htm#BABBDHBB), nor [Oracle Call Interface Programmer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNOCI/oci12oty.htm#LNOCI16891) do mention it explicitly and noone seems to know for sure, it appears that you **just can't** bind `varchar2`-indexed associative arrays. I tried it from C# (via ODP.NET 10.2) and from PHP 5.something (via OCI), with no success.

Comment: I discussed this topic with my colleagues we have also reached the same conclusion. In all manual work only with integer indexed. 
This problem could be bypass by using a data type object. Maybe. 
I will try it

Comment: For .NET->DB interface APIs I've been designing (and for some other projects I've just walked by), they used decomposition of structured data to several scalar-typed associative arrays of identical length, then re-composing them on the DB side to collections of records or varchar2-indexed arrays again. That was back then with ODP.NET 10. I guess I've seen some info on passing (pls_integer-indexed or varray) collections of structures/records from .NET to DB directly in ODP.NET 11+, but, alas, from here you are on your own, I'm not experienced with ODP.NET 11+ so as to help you. :-(

Answer (score 0):

So I tried to use a data type object.

In first step I create data_type object

```
create or replace type STB_JIG_TARLOG_VALUE as object
(
    NAME varchar2(300),
    VALUE varchar2(500)
)
```

and

```
create or replace type
    STB_JIG_TARLOG_VALUES is table of STB_JIG_TARLOG_VALUE
```

They are not part of package.

I can now use this type also as the return type of the function:

```
function get_data(...) return STB_JIG_TARLOG_VALUES
  is 
   items STB_JIG_TARLOG_VALUES := STB_JIG_TARLOG_VALUES();
  begin
   items.extend;
   items(1):= STB_JIG_TARLOG_VALUE('key_name','key_value');
   ...
end get_data;
```

and finally we get the return value simply select:

```
select * from table (get_data(...));
```

Names of columns are defined in STB_JIG_TARLOG_VALUE and adding value to the return value can be different ways (for example loop...)

And get data from this query is not problem with DataReader.