# How to call a stored procedure (with user parameter) via code?

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

From my C# program, I need to call a stored procedure in an Oracle database, which has the following contract:

```
PKG_ENTITY.ALTER_ENTITY (VARCHAR2 NAME, VARCHAR2 FULLNAME, ATTRS_TYPE ATTRS, VARCHAR2 STATUS, INTEGER OUT RESULT, VARCHAR2 OUT ERRORMSG).
```

The `RESULT` and `ERRORMSG` parameters are `OUT` parameters.

I know about the `ATTRS_TYPE` type that it is specified:

```
TYPE ATTRS_TYPE IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(2000) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(30);
```

I used to call this stored procedure as follows:

```
 private void ExecuteNonQuery(string query, params OracleParameter[] parameters)
 {
      using (var connection = new OracleConnection(_connectionString))
      {
            var command = new OracleCommand(query, connection) { CommandType = CommandType.Text };
            connection.Open();
            command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
 }
```

where query =

```
DECLARE
    tNAME varchar2(100);
    tATTRS PKG_ENTITY.ATTRS_TYPE;

    tRESULT INTEGER;
    tERRORMSG varchar2(100);


BEGIN

    tNAME := :pEntityId;

     tATTRS(:pPropId) := :pPropValue;

    PKG_ENTITY.ALTER_ENTITY(tUSERNAME,NULL,tATTRS,NULL,tRESULT,tERRORMSG);
END;
```

Parameter values: pEntityId, pPropId and pPropValue are defined in the code.

Everything was fine, but then I received the requirement that it is necessary to log out values of the tRESULT and tERRORMSG parameters and with this I had great difficulties. I wanted to modify the query by adding a SELECT after calling the stored procedure. Like that:

```
DECLARE
    tNAME varchar2(100);
    tATTRS PKG_ENTITY.ATTRS_TYPE;

    tRESULT INTEGER;
    tERRORMSG varchar2(100);


BEGIN

    tNAME := :pEntityId;

     tATTRS(:pPropId) := :pPropValue;

    PKG_USER.ALTER_USER(tUSERNAME,NULL,tATTRS,NULL,tRESULT,tERRORMSG);
    SELECT tRESULT, tERRORMSG FROM DUAL;
END;
```

But such a query is not correct from the point of view of the `pl/sql` language. Therefore, I came to the conclusion that I need to use the stored procedure call directly and the code should look something like this:

```
private ProcedureResult ExecuteStoredProcedure(string procedureName)
{
    using (var connection = new OracleConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        var command = new OracleCommand(procedureName, connection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };
        connection.Open();
        command.Parameters.Add("NAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2, "New name", ParameterDirection.Input);
        command.Parameters.Add("FULLNAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2, "New fullname", ParameterDirection.Input);
        var attr = new EntityAttribute() { attribute1 = "id", attribute2 = "value"};
        command.Parameters.Add("ATTRS", EntityAttribute, "New fullname", ParameterDirection.Input);
        command.Parameters.Add("STATUS", OracleDbType.Varchar2, "Status", ParameterDirection.Input);
        command.Parameters.Add("RESULT", OracleDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        command.Parameters.Add("ERRORMSG", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        return new ProcedureResult()
        {
            StatusCode = int.Parse(command.Parameters["RESULT"].Value.ToString()),
            Message = command.Parameters["ERRORMSG"].Value.ToString()
        };
    }
}
```

And here I had difficulties with the `PKG_ENTITY.ATTRS_TYPE` type definition.

```
TYPE ATTRS_TYPE IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (2000) INDEX BY VARCHAR2 (30);
```

I know that there is an `IOracleCustomType` interface, but I don’t understand how to implement it correctly.

For example

```
[OracleCustomTypeMapping("PKG_ENTITY.ATTRS_TYPE")]
public class EntityAttribute : INullable, IOracleCustomType
{
    [OracleObjectMapping("ATTRIBUTE1")]
    public string attribute1 { get; set; }
    [OracleObjectMapping("ATTRIBUTE2")]
    public string attribute2 { get; set; }

    public bool IsNull => throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    public void FromCustomObject(OracleConnection con, IntPtr pUdt)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); 
    }

    public void ToCustomObject(OracleConnection con, IntPtr pUdt)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

What should be the names of the fields of this class? I understand that 'ATTRIBUTE1' and 'ATTRIBUTE2' are not valid names.

Comment: You are never adding the `RESULT` and `ERRORMSG` paramters to the command before the execution. Check [how to add output parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247921/how-to-return-oracle-output-parameters-from-a-stored-procedure-in-net)

Comment: @bradbury9 I add parameters in this line of code 'command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);'. In any case, the question is not this.

Comment: That line does not say what does that array contain. Edit your question and add the array declaration. An example of output parameter: `.Parameters.Add("return_code", OracleDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;`. BTW, in your PL/SQL the parameters are not declared as OUTPUT

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294433/using-pl-sql-assoc-array-index-by-varchar2-in-c-sharp) states that you cannot pass an `INDEX BY VARCHAR2` associative array in C#. Instead, you can build the associative array in an anonymous PL/SQL block and call the procedure from there (as you were doing originally).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294433/using-pl-sql-assoc-array-index-by-varchar2-in-c-sharp) states that you cannot pass an `INDEX BY VARCHAR2` associative array in C#. Instead, you can build the associative array in an anonymous PL/SQL block and call the procedure from there (as you were doing originally).

So you could use:

```
DECLARE
  tATTRS PKG_ENTITY.ATTRS_TYPE;
BEGIN
  tATTRS(:pPropId) := :pPropValue;

  PKG_USER.ALTER_USER(
    NAME     => :pEntityId,
    USERNAME => NULL,
    ATTRS    => tATTRS,
    STATUS   => NULL,
    RESULT   => :pResult,
    ERRORMSG => :pErrorMsg
  );
END;
```

Then pass in the parameters `pPropId`, `pPropValue` and `pEntityId` with the direction of  `ParameterDirection.Input` as you were doing and pass `pResult` and `pErrorMsg` with the direction of `ParameterDirection.Output`.

Comment: I do not understand how to pass and get out parameters in this case. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the PL stored procedure should be

```
PKG_ENTITY.ALTER_ENTITY (VARCHAR2 NAME, VARCHAR2 FULLNAME, ATTRS_TYPE ATTRS, VARCHAR2 STATUS, INTEGER OUT RESULT, VARCHAR2 OUT ERRORMSG)
```

Do note that `OUT` was added to the parameter declaration.

And in the `c#`code you would need to make sure the parameters are marked as output

```
.Parameters.Add("RESULT", OracleDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Once done, you would just need to assign the desired value to the parameters in your PL/SQL stored procedure.

```
RESULT:= 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling a PL/SQL procedure is much simpler (not tested, but I assume you will get the idea):

```
var cmd = new OracleCommand("BEGIN PKG_ENTITY.ALTER_ENTITY(:NAME, :FULLNAME, :ATTRS, :STATUS, :RESULT, :ERRORMSG); END;"), connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

// should work as well
// var cmd = new SqlCommand("PKG_ENTITY.ALTER_ENTITY(:NAME, :FULLNAME, :ATTRS, :STATUS, :RESULT, :ERRORMSG)"), connection);
// cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


cmd.Parameters.Add("NAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = "New name"
cmd.Parameters.Add("FULLNAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = "New fullname"

par = cmd.Parameters.Add("ATTRS", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
par.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
var arr string[] = new string[] {"id" , "value"};
par.Value = arr;
par.Size = arr .Count;

cmd.Parameters.Add("STATUS", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = "Status";
cmd.Parameters.Add("RESULT", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);
cmd.Parameters("RESULT").DbType = DbType.Int32;
cmd.Parameters.Add("ERRORMSG", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 100, null, ParameterDirection.Output);
cmd.Parameters("ERRORMSG").DbType = DbType.String;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
var result = System.Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters("RESULT").Value);
var errmsg = cmd.Parameters("ERRORMSG").Value.ToString();
```

Maybe this one helps: [PL/SQL Associative Array Binding](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/featOraCommand.htm#BABBDHBB)

Actually, I don't remember anymore why I do `cmd.Parameters("RESULT").DbType = DbType.Int32;`. Perhaps it was needed to make my code compatible for ODP.NET Provider 1.x and 2.0, see [Mandatory Migration of .NET 1.x Stored Procedures to .NET 2.0 or Later](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51173_01/win.122/e18596/install.htm#CLRNT195)

Comment: The OP's data type is `INDEX BY VARCHAR2(30)`. Will this work for that data-type? [This answer says that it won't.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294433/using-pl-sql-assoc-array-index-by-varchar2-in-c-sharp) If it does, will it map the input `new string[] {"id" , "value"}` to the key-value pair or will it map it to `"0"->"id","1"->"value"`?

Comment: @MT0 you are right, I missed that. Apparently it does not work with `INDEX BY VARCHAR2(30)`. In my answer I was more focused on phrase "necessary to log out values of the tRESULT and tERRORMSG parameters and with this I had great difficulties"